# How can I make a view for a section of Index.html separately?

Tags: python, django, django-views

So, I have a website where the user clicks "my blog" on the navbar, which scrolls down to that section of the index.html (ex. 8000/#blog-section). I already have the Contact form working on the index page.
Now I am trying to create the blog logic to render out three blog posts, but it is showing up blank?

Can I create a separate view for the same "index.html" page?

**Views.py**

```
def index_view(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_on')
    context ={
        'posts': posts,
        'name': name,
    }
    form = ContactForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # Send email goes here
            name = request.POST.get('name')
            subject = request.POST.get('subject')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            message = request.POST.get('message')

            template = get_template('contact_form.txt')
            context = {
                'subject': subject,
                'email' : email,
                'message' : message
            }

            content = template.render(context)

            email = EmailMessage(
                "Message from Portfolio",
                content,
                "New inquiry | Portfolio" + '',
                ['myemail@gmail.com'],
                headers = {'Reply to': email}
            )
        email.send()

        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form}, context)
```

**Urls.py /blog**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.blog_index, name="blog_index"),
    path("<int:pk>/", views.blog_detail, name="blog_detail"),
    path("<category>/", views.blog_category, name="blog_category"),
]
```

**Urls.py /portfolio**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from .views import index_view, post_view
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    path('', index_view),
    path('post/', post_view),
    path("#blog-section/", include("blog.urls")),
]
```

**Template**

```
 <div class="row d-flex">
            {% for post in posts %}
            <div class="col-md-4 d-flex ftco-animate">
                <div class="blog-entry justify-content-end">
                    <a href="single.html" class="block-20"
                        style="background-image: url('{{ post.post_img.url }}');">
                    </a>
                    <div class="text mt-3 float-right d-block">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 meta">
                            <p class="mb-0">
                                <span class="mr-2">{{ post.created_on.date }}|&nbsp;
                                Categories:&nbsp;</span>
                                <a href="#" class="mr-2">Admin</a>
                                <a href="#" class="meta-chat"><span class="icon-chat"></span> 3</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <h3 class="heading"><a href="{% url 'blog_detail' post.pk%}">{{post.title}}</a></h3>
                        <p>{{post.overview}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

Comment: `form = ContactForm()` missing parenthesis

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up , must have got deleted when I was reformatting on here. The contact form works but do you know how to make blog post render from the same index view?

Comment: Actually you can, but you have to combine all things into the context object and then pass it to `render` method. On `index.html` just append the template on your question into it.

Comment: I get this message "UnboundLocalError at /
local variable 'context' referenced before assignment" 
could this line: "content = template.render(context)" be interfering with the context? Or maybe because its out of scope? I appreciate your time!

Comment: That was it!!! It was out of the scope, I had to remove it out of the if statement!  Thanks again for your time!!

Comment: That's because you're trying to do something with context in inner scope which doesn't know where is the context, so try to use another name because that might make Python confuse and even us who read the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason you have put your posts in a separate dictionary from the form. That's not how it works. Put all the context in a single dict.

```
context = {
    'posts': posts,
    'name': name,
    'form': form
}

return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

And to answer your question: no you can't (at least not without building up your page with Ajax). One URL equates to one view.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I made the adjustments, I recieved:

UnboundLocalError at / local variable 'name' referenced before assignment'

Comment: Well you would have got that with your original code. What is `name` supposed to be? Where do you define it?

Comment: I think it suppose to be this `context ={
        'posts': posts,
        'name': name,
    }` name variable not defined yet.

Comment: I have a contact form .txt file template for my Contact me section, It has name, subject, email, message. Wondering if this could be interfering in some way? When I put the context back into the if statement the traceback goes away